# Error in the sql command line

Tags: sql, database, command-line

Every time I insert new data to my table using the command line, it is inserted successfully (and I check my insertion by typing `select * from table_name;`) but when I close the command line and open it again and write the sql statement which (`select * from table_name;`) it says that there are no rows selected. I mean the inserted row is not saved in the database.

Please can someone help me to know the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide us some more information? Is it a memory table, show us the table structure?

Comment: How should I commit ? I don't understand what do u mean ? and where should I use it ? And I use the same username  and pass. ??

Comment: just write after inserts statements:   commit;

Comment: Yeah Thanks it works but can I know why I face this problem and when I should use this command coz I don't use it before and everything was working fine with me ?

Comment: Usually in most DBMS all SQL commands are executed in a TRANSACTION. In some cases DB acces drivers, apps depending of configuration call COMMIT automatically for you (in case you forgot) if you did not COMMIT or ROLLBACK explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [COMMIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_%28data_management%29); to apply your SQL statements